# store array of custom class with nested custom class to standardUserDefaults

Tags: swift, class, nsuserdefaults

Swift 2
Xcoode 7.3

I try to store this:

`var someArray = [Class1(id: 1, titel: "Titel 2", something: Class2(somevar: 20))]`

with NSUSerDefaults:

`let arrayData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(someArray)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(arrayData, forKey: "array")`

My classes look like this:

```
class Class1 {

var id: Int
var titel: String!
var something: Class2



init(id: Int, titel: String, something: Class2) {
    self.id = id
    self.titel = titel
    self.something = something

}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.id = aDecoder.decodeIntForKey("id")
    self.titel = aDecoder.decodeStringForKey("titel")
    ???
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(id, forKey: "id")
    aCoder.encodeObject(titel, forKey: "titel")
???
}


class Class2: Class1
{

var somevar: Int

init(setback: Int)  {
    self.somevar = somevar
}

}
```

What do I need to add in those classes?

(Have to add some mor details; but I think it's self-explaining)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's very easy.

write:

```
self.something = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("something") as! Class2
```

read:

```
aCoder.encodeObject(something, forKey: "something")
```

Answer (score 1):

Uses @FLX code sample and ensure every object in your object's tree also conforms to NSCoding.